# MongoDB Map&Reduce much slower than MySQL group by

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mapreduce

I am trying to evaluate which Databasesystem to use for a new Project.

At the moment I compare MySQL and MongoDB for the task at hand.

I have abotu 5 Million Recoreds with 350 Numeric fields, and I have to use this data to provide different granularity levels for some graph plotting.

I pumped the data into a MongoDB and into a Mysql, and on Mysql I generated some interim tables with 10/th, 100/th and 1000/th of the granularity. The application then chooses the correct table that matches best for the current task and then queries the data there.

With this technique I can get the data fast enough ( < 100 ms).
The SQL query I use is:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(CAST(FLOOR(MIN(STAMP/1000)) AS SIGNED INTEGER)),
MIN(RING),MIN(STATE),CAST(FLOOR(MIN(STAMP)) as SIGNED INTEGER),AVG(w21030401)
FROM project1 GROUP BY FLOOR((stamp - 1181589892000)/60000);
```

I use the identical query for creating the interim tables. The only difference is, tat there are 350 wXXXXXX fields.

```
INSERT INTO project1_10 (TTIME,RING,STATE,STAMP,w21030401,.........)
SELECT from_unixtime(CAST(FLOOR(MIN(STAMP/1000)) AS SIGNED INTEGER)),
MIN(RING),MIN(STATE),CAST(FLOOR(MIN(STAMP)) as SIGNED INTEGER),AVG(w21030401),.......
FROM project1 GROUP BY FLOOR((stamp - 1181589892000)/60000);
```

Then I tried to do the same thing with MongoDB.
I pumed all the data into MongoDB and got 4,8 Million documents in the Form:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50040b3f0cf2872a8d3af90d"), "TTIME" : 
ISODate("2008-11-30T06:40:07Z"), "STAMP" : NumberLong("1228027207000"), 
"STATE" : 2531, "RING" : 1, "w13010096" : 34.991, "w13010097" : 1.432, 
"w23010001" : 292, "w18030180" : 84, "w18030380" : 95, "w21030002" : 51.113, 
"w21030005" : 60.321, "w21030004" : 274.662, "w21030008" : 149.629, 
"w21030009" : 126.565, "w21030010" : 576.296, ........... }
```

Then I tried to generate the Interim Documents with the following mapReduce:

```
keylist =  [ 'w21030401', 'w13011114', ....  ];

m = function (){
    var result = {};
    result['STAMP'] = this['STAMP'];
    result['RING'] = this['RING'];
    result['TTIME'] = this['TTIME'];
    result['STATE'] = this['STATE'];
    for(var key in keylist){
        if(key in this) {
            result[key] = this[key];
            result['cnt_' + key] = 1;
        }
    }
    var zone = Math.floor((this['STAMP'] - 1171004118000) / 1000000);
    emit( zone , result );
};
r = function (name, values){
    var result = {};
    result['STAMP'] = values[0]['STAMP'];
    result['RING'] = values[0]['RING'];
    result['TTIME'] = values[0]['TTIME'];
    result['STATE'] = values[0]['STATE'];
    for(var key in keylist) {
        result[key] = 0;
        result['cnt_' + key] = 0;
    }
    for ( var i=0; i<values.length; i++ ) {
        if(values[i]['STAMP'] < result['STAMP']) {
            result['STAMP'] = values[i]['STAMP'];
            result['TTIME'] = values[i]['TTIME'];
        }
        if(values[i]['RING'] < result['RING']) {
            result['RING'] = values[i]['RING'];
        }
        if(values[i]['STATE'] < result['STATE']) {
            result['STATE'] = values[i]['STATE'];
        }
        for(var key in keylist) {
            if(key in values[i]) {
                result[key] += values[i][key];
                result['cnt_' + key] += values[i]['cnt_' + key];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
};
f = function(who, val){
    var result = {};
    result['STAMP'] = val['STAMP'];
    result['RING'] = val['RING'];
    result['TTIME'] = val['TTIME'];
    result['STATE'] = val['STATE'];
    for(var key in keylist) {
        if(key in val) {
            result[key] = val[key]/val['cnt_'+key];
        }
    }
    return result;
};



db.project1.mapReduce( m, r, { finalize : f, scope: { keylist: keylist }, out : {replace : 'project1_100'} , jsMode : false });
```

MySQL used 210 Seconds for the creation fo the Interim Table, MongoDB used about 4 Hours.

My Question is:
Is MongoDB not suitable for my Problem, do I just need bigger Hardware for MongoDB than for MySQL, or did I do something wrong wih my MapReduce

Thanks

Peter

Comment: Do you have indexes on the mongodb collection ?

Comment: @golja I do have an index on "STAMP", but for the initial building of the reduced Collection I doubt it can be used.

Comment: how do you load the data into Mongo?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here.  You have some min/max/avg/group by operations, but I don't understand the functional requirement.  Can you express what you're trying to do in words?  MongoDB is a non-relational database: it will not perform as well as it can if you approach your problem thinking relationally.

Comment: Thats quite easy, I need to draw Graphs. And to do that I have to aggregate the data, so I have a good number of datapoints to plot. So lets assume I need 200 Points to plot the graph, and the timeframe that needs to be plottet has 200 000 datapoints, then I need to aggregate 1000 points to one, to be able to draw the graph efficiently. For speed up I create some interim tables with pre agggregated data, (see question).

Comment: I understand that you're doing pre-aggregation.  What I don't understand is what your algorithm is for pre-aggregating.  When you aggregate 1000 points into one, what values are you calculating and how are you calculating them?